# How to add CSS with this HTML file?

Tags: css, webpack, css-loader

*Removed content.*

Reading documentation beforehand is important to minimize recurring questions.

Refer to [Webpack v2 documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/).

Answer (score 1):

/config/webpack.config.prod.js

in this file 
new ExtractTextPlugin('static/css/[name].css'),

look this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZzrAQjfuZ0

Comment: Perhaps this is brought by my naivety towards Webpack. I see that I need to add this to my webpack configuration file. Thanks.